# How do we know the Earth's core is Molten with Seismology?

Tags: acoustics, earth, planets, geophysics

My current knowledge about how the core of the earth was discovered is the observation made from non returning/reflecting sonar signal when sent to deeper depths through the earth's  crust/mantle. How was it inferred that the the core was molten?

Comment: It is currently thought that there exists an [outer core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_core) and an [inner core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_core).  The outer core is molten, but the inner core is thought to be solid.  The methods used to determine this are basically described in Ron Jeffries' answer.

Comment: BTW: I (with help) just landed a seismometer on Mars a few hours ago.

Comment: When you say 'sonar signals' are 'sent', that suggests that artificial signals are sent using some kind of seismologist's apparatus. That is certainly not the case -- such signals would never make it down that far. Instead, the vibrations caused by earthquakes are monitored by different stations around the world.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are basically two types of waves - shear (s) waves and primary (p) compression waves.

P waves can travel through solids and liquids but s waves do not travel in fluids.

That p waves, but not s waves, are detected from events occurring on the other side of the globe tells you that there is fluid in the way.

This is the basic picture; it is complicated/enhanced by refraction and dispersion of the waves.